# Disable animation on specific view/state in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I have added a custom "in/out" animation on a state called "browser" with [Native Page Transitions](https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/NativePageTransitions) using this inside my controller

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function() {

        // animate things on devices
        window.plugins.nativepagetransitions.slide(
          {"direction":"up"},
                function (msg) { // called when the animation has finished
                    console.log("success: " + msg);
                },
                function (msg) {
                    alert("error: " + msg);
                }
        );
    });

$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeLeave', function() {

        // animate things on devices
        window.plugins.nativepagetransitions.slide(
          {"direction":"down"},
                function (msg) { // called when the animation has finished
                    console.log("success: " + msg);
                },
                function (msg) {
                    alert("error: " + msg);
                }
        );
    });
```

It works...kind of. The default transition (slide left/right) still works given my "slide up" animation a feeling of "slide in diagonal".

Is there a way to prevent the default transition of being triggered?

This is my view

```
<ion-view >
<ion-nav-bar animation="no-animation">
</ion-nav-bar>

<ion-nav-view animation="no-animation"></ion-nav-view>


<ion-nav-buttons>

        <span class="ion-android-close close_browser" ng-click="goBack()"></span>

</ion-nav-buttons>

<ion-nav-title>
    <img src="img/logo_header.png">
</ion-nav-title>

<ion-content>


    <iframe class="browser" src="{{externalURL}}"></iframe>


</ion-content>
```

Those `animation="no-animation"` doesn't work...

ionic: 1.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to put this before the `$state.go()`

```
$ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
    disableAnimate: true
});
```